# PDF Reader module not displaying pdf

Tags: files

I'm using the PDF Reader module to try to display a pdf file. Ideally I'll use the Goolge Viewer, but as of right now none of the displayers display my pdf.

My pdf file is set to full chmod 777 as well as the directory containing it (site/default/files/), for testing purposes only right now just to make sure the error wasn't due to permissions.

Here is screenshot of what I'm seeing - [image]

I can click the 'try downloading the file here' link and view/save the file.

Any ideas?

EDIT: The screenshot is from a dev server connected to the internet.

Comment: Are you sure your Drupal-Installation is reachable from the internet (e.g. if you are using a dev-server via lan) - then google docs would not be able to access the docment.

Comment: Did you set the proper content type settings for the file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should test this module on the live site, but not on the localhost. If you are testing on localhost, Google Docs Viewer will not be able to access in the PDF document and can't show it, but you can download it from local server.